# Embedding Vimeo Pro and using Vimeo Player in mobile app

Tags: ionic3, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to figure out how I can embed a protected Vimeo Pro video (from my account) in my mobile app

I am using Ionic and it seems to work fine with the embed code which launches the vimeo player.

However I don't know how I will retrieve protected content? I assume I need to use the Player API but cant find any details around how to do this.
If anyone has any idea please let me know